# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: globalThis?.crypto?.randomUUID is not a function (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, random, typeerror, uuid

I just started getting the Uncaught error today in Chrome (maybe after a Chrome update). Firefox doesn't give me the same error. It reads:

```
VM2540:2610 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: globalThis?.crypto?.randomUUID is not a function
    at Messaging.request (<anonymous>:2610:44)
    at ClickToLoad.init (<anonymous>:11216:59)
    at ClickToLoad.callInit (<anonymous>:3180:18)
    at <anonymous>:11424:33
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.init (<anonymous>:11422:26)
request @ VM2540:2610
init @ VM2540:11216
callInit @ VM2540:3180
(anonymous) @ VM2540:11424
init @ VM2540:11422
await in init (async)
apply @ VM2540:11490
```

(anonymous) @ VM2558:3
(anonymous) @ VM2558:5
inject @ inject.js:114
(anonymous) @ inject.js:208

Thoughts?

Works in Firefox and Edge.

Comment: Woke up to the same issue; Laravel 10 + Chrome Version 118.0.5993.70.

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by the browser extension "DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials", currently version 2023.10.12. Appears only on pages loaded via http, not https.